# how to create script for downloading random youtube videos?

Tags: unix

**i need a script that:**

- *creates a folder in the current path named videos*
- *continuously checks, via pwgen, if randomly generated youtube URLs retrieve valid URLs*
- *when a URL is created launches a parallel process to download youtube or vimeo videos*
- *the youtube videos are encoded in *.mov and stored in the movie folder*
- *the names range from 1 to infinite*
- *when the video download finishes the parallel process stops*
- *when the script stops it deletes de movie folder*

**the purpose of this script is to:**

- *create an interactive installation with openframeworks, or a similar tool*

**i want to use:**

- *youtube-dl, ffmpeg and pwgen*

**I will be using:**

- *mac os high sierra*
- *everything will be opensource and published on github*

**pwgen will have to take as arguments:**

- *the number of necessary characters to form a url and the number of hashes to generate*

**youtube-dl and ffmpeg will start from something like:**

- *youtube-dl -t mov URL*

**that's all i know by now**

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: You need to describe the procedure you followed, including the inputs and expected output. Describe any steps you tried to solve this. It will help the community to provide you an answer. Your post looks like specifications that someone would use to actually do the task.

Answer (score 0):

while true; do video_id=$(LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9_-' < /dev/urandom | head -c 11) if [[ $(curl -s --head -w %{http_code} https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id -o /dev/null) = 200 ]]; then youtube-dl -t mov youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$video_id fi done

Comment: i got to this by tweaking an example someone gave me at reddit, so most of the credit goes for the person. i just added in the script for downloading and converting videos with youtube-dl and ffmpeg